Is there a way to setContent within TipTap editor within a particular element?
I am using setContent, but it replaces everything within the editor. I only want to update the content in a particular location within the editor. Currently I have it hooking into the editor with an onChange event that runs the setContent command, and pass in state variables. This works but the problem is that once I introduce a new variable to update, I have to pass in all of the elements over again, and manage them that way. So my command looks like
function onChangeText(e){
editor?.commands.setContent(
`
<h1>${SOMETEXT}</h1>
<Custom Elment>${e.target.value}</Custom Element>
`
}

<h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
<Custom Element> UPDATE THIS TEXT ONLY </Custom Element>


Can you please provide some more code? where you placed onChangeText? and how an editor is rendered.

So basically you have multiple states containing different values of editors's element like one for title and one for h1 ...etc.
Now you don't want to pass all the element values when you update a single one.
In this case, you need to have a separate state for the editor's content.
const [editorContent,setEditorContent]=useState("");//initially blank
Along with this, you have other elements state  like h1 and customer text,
 const [h1Text,setH1Text]=useState('');
 const [customText,setCustomText]=useState('');

then you will add useEffect with the above states as dependencies
like
 useEffect(()=>{
 editor?.commands.setContent(
  `
    <h1>${h1Text}</h1>
    <Custom Elment>${customText}</Custom Element>
  `});  

 },[h1Text,customText,editor]);

Your event handler should now look like this
function onChangeText(e){
  setCustomText(e.target.value);
}

Now whenever any state updates it will be reflected to editor content due to useEffect hook.
I hope this will help :)
